# Деление слова на слоги

Tags: словообразование, слоги

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как разделить на слоги слово *захромал*? *За-хро-мал*?

Учитель исправил у первоклассницы следующим образом:ЗАХ-РО-МАЛ?

Comment: О слогах можете   прочитать здесь:[Слог](http://gramota.ru/book/litnevskaya.php?part1.htm#7) Заодно можете показать и педагогу, чтобы доказать, что она неправа.

Answer (score 3):

Правильно, именно так: ***за-хро-мал.***

Comment: Учитель исправил у первоклассницы следующим образом: ЗАХ-РО-МАЛ.

Comment: Учителя тоже иногда ошибаются.

Comment: Матвей,и  мы всей семьей об этом подумали!